# What exactly should an attribute can considered as derived?

Tags: relational-database, erd

[image]

I am new to erd-model and concepts. Just wondering when can an attribute be derived? E.g when the attribute requires certain formula to compute?

In my case my attribute SectionsOffered is to capture the number of sections available for the course hence should my SectionsOffered be a simple attribute or a case of derived attribute since i can count the number of sections tied to the course?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Generically a "derived" attribute is one that could be determined by a query on a version of the DB without it. But maybe you saw it used for "computed"/"calculated" or "normalized". You saw this word in some context--textbook/method/product/project--which? What did you learn researching it generally & in context? Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.